# How can I use a variable as a key in an object?

Tags: javascript

Is this possible? The real world example is here:

```
var userKey = "userIdKey";

chrome.storage.sync.set({ userKey: "Hello World" }, function () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(userKey, function (data) {
        console.log("In sync:", data);
    });

    console.log("Success");
});
```

This example currently fails because the getter looks for "userIdKey" where as the setter interprets the variable literally as "userKey"

**UPDATE:** I am fully aware of accessing a variable via array notation. The realworld example I have provided is for the *creation* of the object. I am hoping to ensure that the same key is always used for getting and setting -- rather than relying on two string constants being kept in sync.

Comment: have you tried `var myObject = {}; myObject[objectKey]='Baz'`?

Comment: So which key do you want now, `userKey` or `userIdKey`?

Comment: I would like to set and retrieve values from "userIdKey". I want the set and get to look at the same location. The current example has the set setting to userKey and the get reading from userIdKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is :

```
    var key = "something";
    Object.defineProperty(d, key, {
        get: function() {return this.getFullYear() },
        set: function(y) { this.setFullYear(y) }
    });
```

Or in your case:

```
chrome.storage.sync.defineProperty(this, userKey, {
    get: function() {return this[userKey];},
    set: function(value) {this[userKey] = value};
});
```

Read [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) for more on this. `Object.prototype.defineProperty` is new and not available in legacy mode, but the polyfill is available as `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__` and `Object.prototype.__defineSetter__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {},
    objectKey = 'Foo',
    myObject[objectKey] = 'Baz';

console.log(myObject[objectKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Access it like an array:

```
myObject['Foo']
```

To set:

```
myObject['Foo'] = "Bar"
```

Or as a variable:

```
var key = "Foo";
myObject[key] = "Bar"
```

Comment: Sorry, I tacked up my real world example. Is there an applicable way to do this when creating an object, not when looking it up?

Comment: It just seems... shocking.. that there's no way to ensure that the same key is used for the getter and setter, you know?

Comment: @SeanAnderson I don't understand that sentence. What do you mean? Use a variable for the key.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'll try to explain. I am trying to get and set a value in chrome.storage.sync. I want to make sure that I call 'get' and 'set' on the same key without having to keep two locations in-sync. As such, I am trying to assign a string constant to a variable such that I can reuse the variable in the 'get' and the 'set.' But, in the 'get', the variable is being interpreted literally because of the alternative syntax possible for creating an object in JavaScript. I am wondering if there's a way to bypass that.

Comment: function Ob(key,val){ this[key]=val; } then  new Ob(userKey, "Hello World")

Comment: @SeanAnderson I see; that's different from the original question--I don't believe there's a straightforward way to do this, although you could create a wrapper function that builds the object for you.